# Add new TabItem to a TabControl using Click Event

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

I'm trying to add a new TabItem to a TabControl. The TabItem's content will be set to a new Frame, and the frame holds the actual Page. A new Tabitem is added each time the button is clicked, this is the code I've come up with.

```
        // initiates the tab item ang assign dumby values (REMOVE BEFORE RELEASE)
        TabItem NewSupportTabItem = new TabItem { Header = "Support #123-98A", ToolTip = "New support ticket #123-98A",
         Name = "NewSupportTabItem"};

        // Creates the Frame
        Frame NewSupportFrame = new Frame();

        // Initializes the main Ticket Page
        SupportTicketDataShell TicketShell = new SupportTicketDataShell();

        // Set the content of the Frame to the Page
        NewSupportFrame.Content = TicketShell;

        // Sets the content of the TabItem to the Frame
        NewSupportTabItem.Content = NewSupportFrame;

        // Adds the TabItem to the TabControl now
        MainTabControl.Items.Add(NewSupportTabItem);

        // Focuses the tab
        NewSupportTabItem.Focus();
```

As with everything in programming, there's an efficient way, a good way and a bad way, and I think I'm leaning more on the latter side.

Comment: **Lacks concrete context:** Code Review requires concrete code from a project, with sufficient context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Pseudocode, stub code, hypothetical code, obfuscated code, and generic best practices are outside the scope of this site. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest learning about `Custom Controls`.  You can take an existing control add whatever properties, etc. you want to the control and every time you initialize a new one, all your defaults will be present.  Here's a reasonably good tutorial for [Custom Controls](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_custom_controls.htm)